# Can I set one hRC to multiple hDC?

Tags: opengl

Can I create a hRC and use wglMakeCurrent() set the hRC to multiple hDCs? I found that every window should have a unique hRC and hDC. Then how can I put the same context to different windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I create a hRC and use wglMakeCurrent() set the hRC to multiple hDCs?

Yes. You can set a HGLRC to one particular HDC at a particular time in one particular thread, but you can switch it at any time. Also you can have an arbitrary number of HLGLRCs made current on the same HDC, each in a different thread.

The only constraint is that the HGLRC and the HDC to be made current with each other must be compatible in their pixelformat.

> I found that every window should have a unique hRC and hDC

That's not correct. Also any window may have an arbitrary number of HDCs.

> Then how can I put the same context to different windows?

By calling wglMakeCurrent with the new HGLRC-HDC combination to make current in the thread that is making the call.

Comment: but I use GetDC(hWnd) to get a hDC from hWnd, and wglCreateContext(hDC) to get the hGLRC. Isn't there a relationship between three of them? The hGLRC I create from current hDC can be used in another hDC with same pixelformat, is that what you mean?

Comment: @whiack: No, the DC that's passed to wglCreateContext is only used to query the pixelformat (of the DC) to which then the GLRC is configured. That's it, there are no strings attached between them. Yes, a GLRC created with one DC can be used with an entirely different DC (even from a different window) that's been configured to the same pixelformat. From the wglCreateContext reference: "*The wglCreateContext function creates a new OpenGL rendering context, which is suitable for drawing on the device referenced by hdc. __The rendering context has the same pixel format as the device context.__*"